# Embedding Domain Restricted videos from Phonegap mobile app

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, vimeo

I was wondering if there was a way to embed the domain restricted videos from Phonegap mobile application either using HTML or using API

Vimeo website gives no hint on this

Any one who have done it please provide points and example

Answer (score 0):

I believe Vimeo's PRO members have direct access to their video files